# Show that $937$ is an inverse of $13$ modulo $2436$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Use the Euclidean Algorithm to see if an inverse exists.

1) 2436 = 13 * 187 + 5 
2) 13 = 5 * 2 + 3
3) 5 = 3 * 1 + 2
4) 3 = 2 * 1 + 1
5) 2 = 1 * 2 + 0

gcd(13,2436) = 1

Find the Bezout coefficients and inverse.

...1) 1 = 3 - 1 * 2
...2) 1 = 3 - 1 * ( 5 - 1 * 3)
...3) 1 = 3 - 1 (5) + 1 (3)
...4) 1 = -1(5) + 4(3)
...5) 1 = -1(5) + 4(13 - 2 * 5)
...6) 1 = -1(5) + 4(13) - 8(5)
...7) 1 = 4(13) - 9(5)
...8) 1 = 4(13) - 9 (2436 - 187 * 13)
...9) 1 = 4(13) - 9(2436) + 1683(13)
...10) 1 = -9(2436) + 1687(13)

Bezout coefficients are -9 and 1687.

1687 is an inverse.

Answer: 937 is not an inverse of 13 modulo 2436.

Comment: $$937\cdot 13=1+2436\cdot 5\implies\;\text{yes, it is}$$

Comment: Seems like too much work. Particularly since the conclusion is incorrect.

Comment: I don't need to use Euclidean Algorithm? I am just using the algorithm the textbook used. Same idea applied to this question.

Comment: You can use the E.A., but in this case is easier: check numerically whether $\;937\cdot 13\;$ equals a multiple of 2436 plus one...calculators are handy here. :)

Comment: I used the algorithm but I don't understand why 937 is not showing up throughout the process.

Comment: @Nicholas I don't read mathematics written without LaTeX: sorry. Anyway, the claim in your question's title is correct, your conclusion is not.

Comment: Probably you should change the title so it says ""Derive" vs. "Show" so that readers don't continue to misinterpret it.

Comment: In step 4, you have $-1(5)+4(3)$ instead of $-1(5)+2(3)$

Comment: @Michael Thanks I see the error during that step! I see 937 as the inverse now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an error in back-substitution going from $3)$ to $4),\,$ namely $\,3 + 1(3) = 2(3),\,$ not $\,4(3).$

I recommend against using the back-substitution version of the extended Euclidean algorithm since it often leads to errors such as above. Instead, using the form [described here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242) yields

$$\begin{array}{rrr}
2436 &  1 &    0\\
13  & 0 & 1\\
5 &  1 &  -187\\
 3 &  -2 & 375\\
   -1 & \color{#c00}5&   \color{#0a0}{-937}\\
     \end{array}$$

where each above line $\,\ a\ \ b\ \ c\ \,$ means that $\ a = 2436\, b + 13\, c.\ $ Therefore

$$ -1 \,=\,  2436\cdot \color{#c00}{5}+ 13(\color{#0a0}{-937})\quad $$

Multiplying the above by $\,-1\,$ yields that $\ {\rm mod}\ 2436\!:\  13\cdot 937\equiv 1,\,$ so $\,13^{-1}\equiv 937$.

The linked post describes the algorithm in great detail, in a way that is easy to remember.

---

Here is another example computing $\rm\ gcd(141,19),\,$ with the equations written explicitly

$$\rm\begin{eqnarray}(1)\quad \color{#C00}{141}\!\ &=&\,\ \ \ 1&\cdot& 141\, +\ 0&\cdot& 19 \\
(2)\quad\ \color{#C00}{19}\ &=&\,\ \ \ 0&\cdot& 141\, +\ 1&\cdot& 19 \\
\color{#940}{(1)-7\,(2)}\, \rightarrow\, (3)\quad\ \ \ \color{#C00}{ 8}\ &=&\,\ \ \ 1&\cdot& 141\, -\ 7&\cdot& 19 \\
\color{#940}{(2)-2\,(3)}\,\rightarrow\,(4)\quad\ \ \ \color{#C00}{3}\ &=&\, {-}2&\cdot& 141\, + 15&\cdot& 19 \\
\color{#940}{(3)-3\,(4)}\,\rightarrow\,(5)\quad \color{#C00}{{-}1}\ &=&\,\ \ \ 7&\cdot& 141\, -\color{#0A0}{ 52}&\cdot& \color{#0A0}{19} \end{eqnarray}\qquad$$

Comment: May you show me how it would look like with back-substitution? I like to see where my back substitution went wrong. I been more used to back substitution to find the inverse since it is the only way it was done in the textbook and in my class.

Comment: I point out the error in an edit to my answer. I *strongly* recommend using the linked method vs. back-substitution.

Comment: I think you have got to go the long way around before you can use shortcuts.

Comment: @Michael The linked algorithm is just as general as the back-substitution method. It simply does the calculation in a different order, which is usually simpler and less-error prone.

Comment: Ah yes! I spot the error. I see 937 as the inverse. Thanks!